# Pandas Multiindex set value based on boolean mask

Tags: python, pandas

The objective is to assign value based on `mask` in a multiindex columns `df` as below. However, the code does not produced  what Im expecting it to be.May I know which part of the code need to be amend?

```
 import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(3)
arrays = [np.hstack([['One']*2, ['Two']*2]) , ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays)
df=  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=list('ABAB'))

df.columns = columns
idx = pd.IndexSlice
mask = df.loc[:,idx[:,'A']]<0
appenddf=pd.DataFrame((),
              index=df.index,
              columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns.levels[0],['iii']]))
appenddf.loc[:,:]='P'
appenddf=appenddf.where(mask, other='N')
```

Expected output

```
One Two
  iii iii
0   P   P
1   N   N
2   N   N
3   P   P
4   N   P
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's replace them:

```
appenddf=pd.DataFrame(mask.replace({True:'N',False:'P'}).values,
              index=df.index,
              columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns.levels[0],['iii']]))
```

**OR**

```
appenddf=mask.replace({True:'N',False:'P'}).rename(columns={'A':'iii'},level=1)
```

output of appenddf:

```
    One     Two
    iii     iii
0   P       P
1   N       N
2   N       N
3   P       P
4   N       P
```

Comment: Hi @Anurag, thanks for tor the suggestion. I have post another extension from the OP here to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68676150/assign-value-based-on-conditional-of-two-multiindex-columns-in-pandas, maybe you can share some thought there. Thankls