# Pandas Multi-index set value based on three different condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements, multi-index

The objective is to create a new multiindex column based on 3 conditions of the column (`B`)

Condition for `B`

```
if B<0
  CONDITION_B='l`
elif B<-1
  CONDITION_B='L`
else
  CONDITION_B='g`
```

Naively, I thought, we can simply create two different mask and replace the value as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68675893/6446053)

```
# Handle CONDITION_B='l` and CONDITION_B='g`

mask_2 = df.loc[:,idx[:,'B']]<0
appenddf_2=mask_2.replace({True:'g',False:'l'}).rename(columns={'A':'iv'},level=1)
```

and then

```
# CONDITION_B='L`
mask_33 = df.loc[:,idx[:,'B']]<-0.1
appenddf_2=mask_33.replace({True:'G'}).rename(columns={'A':'iv'},level=1)
```

As expected, this will throw an error

```
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, bool found
```

May I know how to handle the 3 different condition

Expected output

```
ONE TWO
B   B
g   L
l   l
l   g
g   l
L   L
```

The code to produce the error is

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(3)
arrays = [np.hstack([['One']*2, ['Two']*2]) , ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays)
df=  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=list('ABAB'))

df.columns = columns

idx = pd.IndexSlice



mask_2 = df.loc[:,idx[:,'B']]<0
appenddf_2=mask_2.replace({True:'g',False:'l'}).rename(columns={'A':'iv'},level=1)
mask_33 = df.loc[:,idx[:,'B']]<-0.1
appenddf_2=mask_33.replace({True:'G'}).rename(columns={'A':'iv'},level=1)
```

Comment: Why not using additional column not mask with new values. Mask values type is Boolean as I see. And you change Boolean to str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

`np.select()` is ideal in this case:

```
conditions=[
    df.loc[:,idx[:,'B']].lt(0) & df.loc[:,idx[:,'B']].gt(-1),
    df.loc[:,idx[:,'B']].lt(-1),
    df.loc[:,idx[:,'B']].ge(0)
]
labels=['l','L','g']
out=pd.DataFrame(np.select(conditions,labels),columns=df.loc[:,idx[:,'B']].columns)
```

OR

via `np.where()`:

```
s=np.where(df.loc[:,idx[:,'B']].lt(0) & df.loc[:,idx[:,'B']].gt(-1),'l',np.where(df.loc[:,idx[:,'B']].lt(-1),'L','g'))
out=pd.DataFrame(s,columns=df.loc[:,idx[:,'B']].columns)
```

output of `out`:

```
   One  Two
    B   B
0   g   L
1   l   l
2   l   g
3   g   l
4   L   L
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you want to do but try something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [ 0, -1, -2, -2, -1,  0,  0, -1, -1, -2]})

df['ONE'] = np.where(df['B'] < 0, 'l', 'g')
df['TWO'] = np.where(df['B'] < -1, 'L', df['ONE'])
df = df.set_index(['ONE', 'TWO'])
```

Output result:

```
>>> df
         B
ONE TWO
g   g    0
l   l   -1
    L   -2
    L   -2
    l   -1
g   g    0
    g    0
l   l   -1
    l   -1
    L   -2
```